# Installing homebrew in Dockerfile - mac

Tags: python, docker, deployment, dockerfile

When I try to install my dependencies in my Dockerfile, I get the error:

```
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
#7 14.90     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This seems to mean I need to install gcc first in my Dockerfile, but as I'm on a mac, that means I need to install brew as well. I've searched for the past two days and can't figure this out, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Heres my docker file

```
FROM python:3
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:4.9.2-5 as conda

COPY requirments.txt .

RUN brew install gcc

RUN pip3 install -r requirments.txt

RUN conda install scikit-learn

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "./src/copia_document_ingestion/dashboard.py"]
```

The reason I'm using conda to install scikit-learn is because I'm on the m1 version of a mac mini

Comment: The thing that you are on Mac has nothing to do with your Dockerfile. Your Docker image is like completely different environment and OS. Based on your parent Docker image. In case of `condaforge/mambaforge` - these images are most likely based on Ubuntu - so you have to install `gcc` like `apt-get update && apt install -y build-essential`

Answer (score 1):

As said by czende:

The thing that you are on Mac has nothing to do with your Dockerfile. Your Docker image is like completely different environment and OS. Based on your parent Docker image. In case of condaforge/mambaforge - these images are most likely based on Ubuntu - so you have to install gcc like apt-get update && apt install -y build-essential

This solved my problem, can't believe I wasted 2 days being this dumb. Thanks!